# 414 Request-URI Too Large

Tags: eventbrite

When trying to create an event with a rich description, I get a "414 Request-URI Too Large" error. I suppose this is expected, since event_new is a GET request, it's bound to happen.

What's the best workaround?

Comment: I would complain until they support POST... that's just ridiculous.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much my point of posting here.

Comment: What is the size of your request?

Comment: The size of the request is variable depending on the content in the Description. Bottom line is that the existing API is now useless for creating rich Descriptions :(



Any ETA on the REST API? I'm not looking for a release date, but more of a "it's only in planning right now" or "on track for this quarter" type answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I work on the platform team at Eventbrite

Currently, there is a hard limit which is enforced by our webservers.  So for the immediate-term, there is no work around.

As noted, creating new events or updating existing events via GET is non-ideal, and we are actively working on building a new API which is more RESTful and does not have issues such as this one.

I will look into the possibility of upping the buffer size limit for our api servers.

Comment: I appreciate your offer to look into the buffer size limit, but it would not be a sufficient fix for us to implement the feature. We want to let our users create a rich HTML description without limits. I'm not talking about anything like a MB of text, but more than what we can do with a GET request.

Like I asked in my comment above, any ETA on the REST api?

Comment: Makes total sense.  Lookout for a more RESTful API sometime this summer....we don't have a hard date just yet.  In the meantime, the max buffer size has been doubled to 16K...which should help for the vast majority of cases.